# Roslyn, getting the symbol and declaring syntax reference of generic types

Tags: .net, roslyn

In my class I have a property which is of a generic type. When I am "walking" the syntax tree, in the `VisitPropertyDeclaration` I get `node.Type is GenericNameSyntax`.

How do I get the corresponding symbol and syntax reference of the property's type?

What I've tried:

- `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol` is null
- `SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node).Type`, `SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node).Type.OriginalDefinition` return the symbol, but the `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` property is null.

I guess the reason this info is missing because generic types are resolved at runtime so the SemanticModel of the just compiled program is not updated with this information?

EDIT: I found out about a compilation error, which I have since fixed. But I am still unable to get DeclaringSyntaxReferences. Could this maybe be because this type is declared in a non-project reference?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could this maybe be because this type is declared in a non-project reference?

You'd see a DeclaringSyntaxReference only if it's a reference to another source project in the same solution. We won't have that if it's coming from a DLL reference. Since you mentioned that SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node).Type was working, chech the symbols' Locations property to see if you're getting references in source or metadata.

If this is a cross-project reference but it is in source, then share the code for how you're getting your Compilation, as the problem may lie there.

Comment: It was out of source. Thanks for the help.