# C# Incremental Source Generator Not Triggering build when generated files are modified

Tags: c#, msbuild, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I have 2 projects, IE: projX.csproj and projY.csproj.

My src generator is referenced by projX, but the code generated is based on classes on projY.

When projY classes change, the generated files should change (and they do), but because no change occurs on projX, the changes are not picked up and no build occurs on projX.
Routes that I'm considering but can't find an answer for:

1. How do I make projX recognize that the generated files have changed?
2. Otherwise, how can I force projX to build when projY changes?

Thank you.

Comment: Are they in the same solution?

Comment: @jwdonahue yes!

Comment: there should be no build on just a change, why do you expect one? pls share more information, for me it seems like you're not running the source generators the intended way.

Comment: 1) The generator finds objects marked with [SomeAttribute] in projY. 
2) The generator uses the found object to generate a modified version of the object itself in projX (the modified objects must be in projX).
3) projX uses the modified version.
4) if I change something in the original class, the generated file is updated, but the compilation doesn't pick it up

Comment: so projX has a project-dependency on projY and you're properly querying the semantic model of projY over something like `compilation.ExternalReferences`?

Comment: I'm using the file path of the class to create a new syntax tree. Is there a way to do it via the roslyn api? Only projX uses the generator

Comment: if projX SG output changes, that should definitely be recognized by projX. however incremental SGs need to be deterministic, if you're creating additional input or output by using the systems file api that might not work properly. if you need it that way you could use a normal SG instead of an incremental one. otherwise like i said before you can query the semantic model of projY over something like `compilation.ExternalReferences`. a value provider for the compilation is in the passed context and generated files are registered on that context

Comment: I'm going to give it a try and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I don't seem to understand how to get the syntax tree from the compilation.ExternalReferences. Could you give me an example? sorry

Comment: yea, it's really a lot basically I use
`compilation.ExternalReferences` gives me references to dependencies of my project, wich i filter by name using the `Display` property and use `compilation.GetAssemblyOrModuleSymbol(reference)` to get an actual symbol

Comment: and does that allow me to get the syntax tree? normally when I try to get it from there I end up with a null tree

Comment: oh... i can see it could be hard to generate from the semantic model and if you actually need the syntaxtree that might be a problem. i remember having similar issues, but a lot has changed in my SG since then... in my current structure i basically have an attribute generated and used in projX like `[GeneratorArgs(Symbol = typeof(ProjYType))]`, where i can get `TypeInfo` from the parameter, with wich i can do stuff like `typeInfo.Type.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.First().SyntaxTree.FilePath` and for me it's not null anymore

Comment: definitely worth a try! thank you. will keep you updated

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. DeclaringSyntaxReferences is empty:
[Attribute(typeof(ClassInTest1))] on top of the projX method that is ready by the SG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best workaround I found for this particular scenario is to add:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="../YourProjectName/*/*.cs"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

What's passed in the include depends on the case, but best to be as specific as possible.
That will add the syntax tree to the compilation as well.

Answer (score 0):

This was too long for a comment.

One thing i think it might be at this point is that you're getting the type the wrong way, I use this to get values from `Expression`s passed to the attribute. it's actually not working for `DefaultExpressionSyntax` at the moment, that's why I'm useing `NamedParameters` in the attribute, to avoid it:

```
public record ValueSymbolInfo(object? Value, TypeInfo? Type);
private ValueSymbolInfo GetValue(SemanticModel semanticModel, ExpressionSyntax expression)
{
    var constantType = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(expression);
    if (expression is TypeOfExpressionSyntax typeOfExpressionSyntax)
        return new(GetValue(semanticModel, typeOfExpressionSyntax.Type).Type, constantType);
    if (expression is DefaultExpressionSyntax defaultExpressionSyntax)
        return new(null, GetValue(semanticModel, defaultExpressionSyntax.Type).Type);
    if (expression is ArrayCreationExpressionSyntax arrayCreationExpressionSyntax)
    {
        var initializer = arrayCreationExpressionSyntax.Initializer;
        var type = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(arrayCreationExpressionSyntax.Type);
        if (initializer is null)
        {
            return new(null, type);
        }
        else
        {
            var expressions = initializer.Expressions;
            var value = expressions.Select(syntax => GetValue(semanticModel, syntax)).Select(info => info?.Value).ToArray();
            return new(value, type);
        }
    }
    var constantValue = semanticModel.GetConstantValue(expression);
    return new(constantValue.HasValue ? constantValue.Value : default, constantType);
}
```

If used on `typeof(ProjYType)` it should return the `TypeInfo` of the referenced type as Value and the `TypeInfo` of `System.Type` as `Type`

otherwise i could only imagine something to be wrong with your project files.

Comment: Right, this gets me the symbol and the object. But I still don't have a way to access the syntaxTree. The location is still metadata. :/

Comment: otherwise i can only imagine, you're referencing the output of the project, instead of referencing the project directly or the needed metadata is explicitly removed from the project reference inside your `.csproj`

Comment: these are the references of projX:
  <ProjectReference Include="..\projY\projY.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\SG\SG.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
No other config in the csproj

Comment: hm... my SG ref looks like `<ProjectReference Include="..\sg\sg.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />`, but can't really imagine `ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"` will make a difference...

Comment: I tried both ways, no luck. That ReferenceOutputAssembly only stops the dll being added to the bin unfortunatelly.

Comment: I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69245350/roslyn-getting-the-symbol-and-declaring-syntax-reference-of-generic-types) it could be the way you get the `SemanticModel` / `Compiliation`, sadly it was something else so they didn't track that down, but the only ways i know to them are via context and `ISyntaxContextReceiver` of wich i use the later